# Problems while trying to see the route between two locations using Google Maps

Tags: android, database, url, android-intent

I'm using a background thread to read from a Sqlite database some GPS data...and I store it in  some GeoPoints.....After I finish reading the data I wanna use an intent in order to see the route described by that data.

Here is my code:

```
protected List<GeoPoint> doInBackground(DBAdapter... db) {
    try {
        db[0].openDataBase();
        Cursor c = db[0].getAllData();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                longitude = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
                latitude = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(1));
                p = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
                geoPointsArray.add(p);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        db[0].close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Eroare", "doInBackground", e);
    }
    return geoPointsArray;
}

protected void onPostExecute(List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray) {
    int i = geoPointsArray.size();
    srcPlace = geoPointsArray.get(1);
    destPlace = geoPointsArray.get(i);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse(" http://maps.google.com?t=k&saddr=" + srcPlace
                    + "&daddr=" + destPlace));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But something, somewhere goes terribly wrong and I get the next output of the logcat:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 4180, size is 4180
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)
 at test.android.screen_database$InitTask.onPostExecute(screen_database.java:201)
 at test.android.screen_database$InitTask.onPostExecute(screen_database.java:1)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Don't forget I wanna see the path on the map between those two points...so  if u have suggestions about the URL are more than welcomed!

UPDATE:This is my second FC

```
thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
 Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= http://maps.google.com?t=k&saddr=48856838,2351068&daddr=48927049,2357270 }    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
at test.android.screen_database$InitTask.onPostExecute(screen_database.java:205)
at test.android.screen_database$InitTask.onPostExecute(screen_database.java:1)
     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array index is based on zero. If `i` is your size, you need to call `destPlace = geoPointsArray.get(i - 1);`. And the source should be `0` and not `1`.

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray) {
    int i = geoPointsArray.size();
    srcPlace = geoPointsArray.get(0);
    destPlace = geoPointsArray.get(i - 1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse(" http://maps.google.com?t=k&saddr=" + srcPlace
                    + "&daddr=" + destPlace));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Well,I solved that but I still get an error....I've update d my question...DO u have any clue what is wrong now??

Comment: try this: http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-map-via-intent I am not sure, that you can display a route in the default map application with an intent. I guess you need to implement your own mapview.

Comment: When I search for this on the google maps saddr=48856838,2351068&daddr=48927049,2357270  it says that it couldn't understand this location!!!Why?

Comment: because saddr and daddr are streets, real addresses and not a longitude/langitude.

Comment: Aha,fantastic...Question:I saw u are from Germany,are u going to Dusseldorf tommorrow??:D.....and how should I make a map of my own in order for that intent to work?:-S....The link provided above doesn't say something like!

Comment: I am not in dusseldorf, I stick to berlin :) I am not sure if you can use the default map to display a route. I guess you need to read the documentation for that... if it isn't possible, you should implement your own map with a mapactivity. There are a lot of tutorials around for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in

```
int i = geoPointsArray.size();
        srcPlace = geoPointsArray.get(1);
        destPlace = geoPointsArray.get(i);
```

needs to be `destPlace = geoPointsArray.get(i-1);`